# Error while creating apk in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

[image: error in console]Error is ---> Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

I followed the documentation [Generate signed apk](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

to generate apk . When I gave the command `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` then I got this error.

My build.grade file is --->

`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
         release {
             if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                 storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                 storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                 keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                 keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
             }
         }
     }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
`
```

Please help me fix this issue.I can run my app in debug mode but  I cant able to generate the realease apk.

Comment: Did you try `./gradlew clean` ?

Comment: Yes. tried it . Same issue again

Comment: Did you try generate signed apk in Android Studio? If you did, what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed.

Issue was with react-navigation module .With latest version of gradle,it was not able to compile the images in react-navigation folder . So I removed the images and ran the command then it worked.

This doc helped me fix it.

[Link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3315)